# Android OpenCV parallelize loops

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, openmp

I know that OpenMP is included in NDK (usage example here: http://recursify.com/blog/2013/08/09/openmp-on-android ). I've done what it says on that page but when I use: *#pragma omp for* on a simple for loop that scans a vector, the app crashes with the famous "fatal signal 11".

What am I missing here? Btw I use a modified example from the Android samples, it's Tutorial 2 Mixed Processing. All I want is to parallelize (multithread) some of the for loops and nested for loops that I have in the jni c++ file while using OpenCV.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated!

Edit: sample code added:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
Mat tmp(iheight, iwidth, CV_8UC1);
for (int x = 0; x < iheight; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < iwidth; y++) {
        int value = (int) buffer[x * iwidth + y];
        tmp.at<uchar>(x, y) = value;
    }
}
```

Based on this: http://www.slideshare.net/noritsuna/how-to-use-openmp-on-native-activity
Thanks!

Comment: Hard to answer without code

Comment: Ok, sample added, my code is based on the this: http://www.slideshare.net/noritsuna/how-to-use-openmp-on-native-activity . I use OpenCV, I've included <omp.h> in my jni file and it crashes with fatal signal 11... I've also tried with a single for loop (or with an if statement) and adding: pragma omp parallel .. still crashes!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a known issue in GOMP, see [Bug 42616](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42616) and [Bug 52738](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52738).
It's about your app will crash if you try to use OpenMP directives or functions on a non-main thread, and can be traced back to the `gomp_thread()` function (*see [libgomp/libgomp.h](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/master/gcc-4.6/libgomp/libgomp.h) @ line 362 and 368*) which returns `NULL` for threads you create:

```
#ifdef HAVE_TLS
    extern __thread struct gomp_thread gomp_tls_data;
    static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
    {
      return &gomp_tls_data;
    }
#else
    extern pthread_key_t gomp_tls_key;
    static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
    {
      return pthread_getspecific (gomp_tls_key);
    }
#endif
```

As you can see GOMP uses different implementation depending on whether or not thread-local storage (TLS) is available.

- If it is available, then `HAVE_TLS` flag is set, and a global variable is used to track the state of each thread,
- Otherwise, thread-local data will be managed via the function `pthread_setspecific`.

In the earlier version of NDKs the thread-local storage (the `__thread` keyword) isn't supported so `HAVE_TLS` won't be defined, therefore `pthread_setspecific` will be used.
*Remark: I'm not sure whether `__thread` is supported or not in the last version of NDK, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191214/no-luck-compiling-thread-using-ndk-clang-3-4-3-5) you can read the same answers about Android TLS.*

When GOMP creates a worker thread, it sets up the thread specific data in the function `gomp_thread_start()` (line 72):

```
#ifdef HAVE_TLS
    thr = &gomp_tls_data;
#else
    struct gomp_thread local_thr;
    thr = &local_thr;
    pthread_setspecific (gomp_tls_key, thr);
#endif
```

But, when the application creates a thread independently, the thread specific data isn't set, and so the `gomp_thread()` function returns `NULL`. This causes the crash and this isn't a problem when TLS is supported, since the global variable that's used will always be available

I remember that this issue had been fixed `android-ndk-r10d`, but it only works with background processes (no Java). It means when you enable OpenMP and create a native thread from JNI (what is called from Java Android) then your app will crash remains.